# Format time of Date Object depending on device locale

Tags: java, android

Depending on the locale device settings I need to format the time of a date either:

```
16:18
```

or

```
4:18 PM
```

I tried this code, since SimpleDateFormat is supposed to use those locale device settings.

```
SimpleDateFormat localTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
localTimeFormat.format(startDate);
result = localTimeFormat.format(startDate));
```

On my phone with NA settings I still get `16:18`

I know that there I can add an `Am/pm marker` with `'a'`, but as I said, I want this to be variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DateFormat.getTimeFormat(Context)` to get a `DateFormat` instance, and use that to format the date instead of creating your own format. This will honor the user's locale and 24-hour time preference from device settings.

Documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getTimeFormat(android.content.Context)

Example:

```
Date date = new Date();
String text = DateFormat.getTimeFormat(MainActivity.this).format(date);
```

Comment: The problem with that is that this would not only print the time of day

Comment: @LisaCleaver `getTimeFormat()` will return a formatter that only prints the time of day